# lua setmetatable - error = attempt to call global 'setmetatable' (a nil value)

Tags: module, lua, vlc

I'm creating one addon for VLC player in LUA (5.1). It should be as small as possible so I do want to integrate all needed functions inside one lua file (I do not want to bother users with additional module files). So I want to embed some functions from external modules directly into my lua file.

I need several bit functions from `numberlua` module: `bxor()`, `band()`, `rshift()`, `lshift()`.

The original code in `numberlua` module looks like this bellow (already shortened and that's all I need from this module), and when I use it as module it works fine, but when I extract these (including few related) functions from module and insert into my lua file (ok M removed) I got the error:

```
attempt to call global 'setmetatable' (a nil value)
```

While inside module setmetatable works, if extracted it does not work!

The code inside module that works:

```
local M = {_TYPE='module', _NAME='bit.numberlua', _VERSION='0.3.1.20120131'}

local MOD = 2^32
local MODM = MOD-1

local function memoize(f)
  local mt = {}
  local t = setmetatable({}, mt)
  function mt:__index(k)
    local v = f(k); t[k] = v
    return v
  end
  return t
end

local function make_bitop_uncached(t, m)
  local function bitop(a, b)
    local res,p = 0,1
    while a ~= 0 and b ~= 0 do
      local am, bm = a%m, b%m
      res = res + t[am][bm]*p
      a = (a - am) / m
      b = (b - bm) / m
      p = p*m
    end
    res = res + (a+b)*p
    return res
  end
  return bitop
end

local function make_bitop(t)
  local op1 = make_bitop_uncached(t,2^1)
  local op2 = memoize(function(a)
    return memoize(function(b)
      return op1(a, b)
    end)
  end)
  return make_bitop_uncached(op2, 2^(t.n or 1))
end

M.bxor = make_bitop {[0]={[0]=0,[1]=1},[1]={[0]=1,[1]=0}, n=4}
local bxor = M.bxor

function M.band(a,b) return ((a+b) - bxor(a,b))/2 end
local band = M.band

function M.bor(a,b)  return MODM - band(MODM - a, MODM - b) end
local bor = M.bor

local lshift, rshift -- forward declare

function M.rshift(a,disp) -- Lua5.2 insipred
  if disp < 0 then return lshift(a,-disp) end
  return math.floor(a % 2^32 / 2^disp)
end
rshift = M.rshift

function M.lshift(a,disp) -- Lua5.2 inspired
  if disp < 0 then return rshift(a,-disp) end 
  return (a * 2^disp) % 2^32
end
lshift = M.lshift

return M
```

So I use it from module lile:

```
local bit = require ("numberlua")
```

and I have rshift like `bit.rshift()`

How to embed functions from module above directly into lua file and use these functions like local ones?

Comment: VLC addon one can find on GitHub (https://github.com/sbrbot/vlc-titlovi). In newer version I succeeded to integrate function from `zzlib` and `inflate-bit32` libraries in my lua file, but not those ones from `numberlua` module.